# Mongoid equivalent of ActiveRecord's "collection?" method for relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, mongoid

I am using Mongoid and trying to do something similar to ActiveRecord's `collection?` method.

I have a method that gets the relations from a class like:

```
def relations
  object.class.relations
end
```

This makes a hash of the relation objects.

Then in another method I am doing this:

```
if relations[key].collection?
   do stuff...
else
   do something else...
end
```

`collection?` isn't a method in this situation like it is in ActiveRecord.
So I get

```
undefined method `collection?' for #<Mongoid::Association::Referenced::BelongsTo:0x00007feed3b61240>
```

What is the Mongoid way of doing this type of conditional?

Comment: Hi there! Mongoid contributor here. Can you link some documentation to the collection? method (I can't seem to find it from some brief googling), and I'll let you know if there's a way for doing a similar thing in mongoid. I'll also be happy to bring up adding this method with the rest of the mongoid team.

Comment: I am trying to track down the collection? docs too. I couldn't find it, but I see it in the  methods. For example, in an Active Record app I can do this:  author.class.reflections['books'].methods
=> [:collection?, ...    And author.class.reflections['books'].collection? => true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the method you're talking about it [this one](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/07f48f781b7d35495b3ea8ff86e9e90c6b3b0526/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L559), which seems like it just returns true on has_many and HABTM associations... As of 8.0 we have the `many?` method to check if its HasMany or and EmbedsMany, but I don't think that is quite what you need. I can suggest a method for right now, and I will open a ticket to see if we can have this added:

```
def collection?(association)
  [
    Mongoid::Association::Referenced::HasMany, 
    Mongoid::Association::Referenced::HasAndBelongsToMany
  ].any? { |r| association.is_a?(r) }
end
```

EDIT: You can track this issue [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-5527).

Comment: This is a good workaround. I will track the issue. I wasn't aware of the AR parity tracker. So +10 for that for sure!